# Max tries exceeded error while loading data to snowflake via snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a csv file from my windows system to snowflake internal stage using snowsql.

Command : `PUT file://C:\Test_Data\Orders_1.csv @CSVSTAGE1;`

Error : `-00001 (n/a): GET with url b'<url>' failed for exceeding maximum retries.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between? It looks to me you're not able to reach the internal stage. Running [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) should help seeing if you have any network filtering in between.